# Reflecting the function $y=f(x)$ about $y=mx+b$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I want to reflect $y=f(x)$ about $y=mx+b$, and I'm struggling a bit to get one more piece of information. What I did so far was call my original point $(x_1,f(x_1))$ and call the point achieved by reflection $(x_2,g(x_2))$. I know that the line connecting these two points will be perpendicular to the line $y=mx+b$. Meaning that it will have a slope of $\frac{-1}{m}$:

$$\frac{g(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{-1}{m}$$

Now I'm trying to figure out how to get "$b$" into use, so I can solve $g(x_2)$ in terms of only $x_2$. Can someone help out or hint me to something, at this moment it's not that clear.

Comment: Okay so I can't really follow what you did in the question. All you need to do is take a line perpendicular to $r$ (call $r$ your line of symmetry) - move it about until it goes through $(x,f(x))$, express it in the form $\ell=tu+v$ where $u,v$ are vectors. such that if $t=0$ then $\ell$ is on your line of symmetry, then you just go to $-t$ where $t$ is such that $\ell$ is $(x,f(x))$

Comment: By considering the effect of reflecting the graph of $f$ in say a steep line, one can see the result might not be a function of $x$ but only a relation in the plane. That is, some $x$ values may have more than one $y$ value for them in the reflected graph.

Comment: An easy example to see this is to reflect the parabola $y=x^2$ over the line $y=x$ in the plane. This is the way most people kind of think about finding inverses of functions - replacing the y's with the x's.  We all know that $\sqrt{x}$ has two values, but thought of as a function we consider only the positive root.

Comment: Is there a way to find the equation of that relation.

Comment: hint: How could you find the point halfway between $(x_1,f(x_1)))$  and $(x_2,f(x_2))$ without knowing $(x_2,f(x_2))$ in advance?

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to get a bit more general.

Suppose we have a line $\ell$ in the plane characterized by $Ax+By+C=0,$ where $A,B,C$ are real and $A,B$ are not both $0$. Let's figure out how to reflect a point $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle$ about $\ell.$

First of all, we note/prove that for any $D\in\Bbb R,$ the line given by $$-Bx+Ay+D=0$$ is perpendicular to $\ell,$ and every line in the plane perpendicular to $\ell$ has such a form.

Second, letting $D=Bx_0-Ay_0,$ we have that $-Bx+Ay+D=0$ is the unique perpendicular of $\ell$ in the plane that passes through $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle.$

Third, we solve the system $$Ax+By+C=0\\-Bx+Ay+Bx_0-Ay_0=0$$ to obtain the unique $\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$ lying on $\ell$ and the given perpendicular.

Finally, we note/prove that $\langle x_2,y_2\rangle$ is the reflection of $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle$ about $\ell$ if and only if $\langle x_1,y_1\rangle$ is the midpoint of $\langle x_0,y_0\rangle$ and $\langle x_2,y_2\rangle,$ from which we can explicitly determine $\langle x_2,y_2\rangle.$

Since every line of the form $y=mx+b$ can be rewritten in the form $Ax+By+C=0,$ you should be able to proceed as such, with $y_0=f(x_0).$

It is worth noting that the reflection of a function in $x$ about a given line *may not be a function in* $x$! For example, consider the reflection of $f(x)=x^2$ about any line that isn't parallel to the $x$-axis.

Comment: Sorry I'm having trouble following along, what is D .

Comment: And isn't the slope of a perpendicular line given by negative multiplicative inverse. So wouldn't the slope of the perpendicular to L be $\frac{-1}{B}$.

Comment: Well, $D$ is simply a real number (that doesn't depend in any way on $A,$ $B,$ or $C$). As for your latter comment, remember that [not all lines have a slope](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1429446/28900).

Comment: Never mind, I see you interchanged the $x$ and $y's$, thanks.